# Finding Elements in Browserstack for iOS

Tags: android, python, ios, mobile, browserstack

I am using browserstack to do automation using Appium. There was no way for me to identify the elements. I am developing a test case using appium and Python as programming language

Answer (score 1):

You can use Appium Desktop to locate the elements. It is possible to integrate Appium Desktop with BrowserStack: https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/appium/appium-desktop

Then you can execute the test cases with Python.